# Relation between `<*>` and `<$>`

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

According to the [Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors), the following relation between `<$>` and `<*>` hold:

```
f <$> x = pure f <*> x
```

They claim that one can prove this theorem as a consequence of the functor and applicative laws.

I do not see how to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since none of the other laws mention `(<$>)` at all, there's something fishy with this claim. If it is correct, parametricity will play a role.

Comment: @DanielWagner The [applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) docs also mention that such law comes from free from the others, but also seem to require `(<*>) = liftA2 id` and `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`. Either this or parametricity looks crucial.

Comment: @chi when they say free, do they mean as a consequence of free theorems?

Comment: Per @DanielWagner and @chi, I think it probably follows from the [uniqueness of `fmap`](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/15384). (Coincidentally that mail appears to be from a thread on this very topic.) There's only one function with that type which satisfies the `fmap id = id` law, so it suffices to show that `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` obeys the `fmap id = id` law as a consequence of the `Applicative` laws.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Ah, right! That's it, I think.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Yes, the free theorem implies that we can't have two implementations of `fmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b` that satisfy `fmap id = id`. By parametricity, any such `fmap` must be the "canonical" one (derived from the type structure in the "natural" way).

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Actually when I above wrote "comes from free" I meant "comes for free", as in "can be derived". Unfortunate typo. Still, Benjamin and Rainbacon now solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

### The Functor and Applicative Laws

Let's start with what the functor and applicative laws are. [Let's take a look at these laws presented in the Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors).

```
fmap id = id                   -- 1st functor law
fmap (g . f) = fmap g . fmap f -- 2nd functor law
```

Now we should look at the applicative laws.

```
pure id <*> v = v                            -- Identity
pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)               -- Homomorphism
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u              -- Interchange
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w) -- Composition
```

> The identity law says that applying the `pure id` morphism does nothing, exactly like with the plain `id` function.
>
> The homomorphism law says that applying a "pure" function to a "pure" value is the same as applying the function to the value in the normal way and then using pure on the result. In a sense, that means pure preserves function application.
>
> The interchange law says that applying a morphism to a "pure" value `pure y` is the same as applying `pure ($ y)` to the morphism. No surprises there - as we have seen in the higher order functions chapter, `($ y)` is the function that supplies `y` as argument to another function.
>
> The composition law says that `pure (.)` composes morphisms similarly to how `(.)` composes functions: applying the composed morphism `pure (.) <*> u <*> v` to `w` gives the same result as applying `u` to the result of applying `v` to `w`.

### What we need to prove in order to prove the relation

Per @benjamin-hodgson

> it suffices to show that `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` obeys the `fmap id = id` law as a consequence of the Applicative laws.

The reason that we only need to show that `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` obeys the `fmap id = id` law is because the second functor law can be shown to follow from the first law. I've provided a brief walk through this proof, but Edward Kmett has a more verbose version [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap)

Section 3.5 of Wadler's [Theorems for Free](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf) provides some work on the function `map`. Based on the idea of free theorems anything that is shown for a function holds for any other function of the same type signature. Since we know that the list is a functor the type of `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` is analogous to the type of `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` which means that all of Wadler's work with map applies to fmap as well.

Wadler's conclusion about map leads to this theorem about fmap:

Given functions `f`, `g`, `k`, and `h` such that `g . h = k . f` then `$map g . fmap h = fmap k . $map' f` with `$map` being the "natural" mapping function for a given functor. The full proof of this theorem is a bit verbose, but Bartosz Milewski provides a good [overview](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/edwardk/the_free_theorem_for_fmap_school_of_haskell_fp_complete/) of it.

We will need two lemmas to show that the second functor law is a consequence of the first.

#### Lemma 1

Given `fmap id = id --the first functor law` then `fmap f = $map f`

```
fmap f = $map id . fmap f   --Because $map id = id
= fmap id . $map f          --Because of the free theorem with g = k = id and h = f
= $map f                    --Because of the first functor law
```

So `fmap f = $map f` and by extension `fmap = $map`

#### Lemma 2

`f . g = id . (f . g)` which is obvious given that `id . v = v`

#### Putting it all together

Given `fmap id = id` then `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`

```
fmap f . fmap g = $map f . fmap g  --Because of lemma 1
= fmap id . $map (f . g)           --Because of the free theorem for fmap and lemma 2
= $map (f . g)                     --Because of the first functor law
= fmap (f . g)                     --Because $map = fmap
```

Therefore, if we can show that the first functor law holds, then the second will also hold.

### Proving the relation

To show that we'll need the Applicative Identity law. Looking at the law we have `pure id <*> v = v` and from the equivalence we are trying to prove `f <$> x = pure f <*> x`. If we let `x = id` then the Applicative Identity law tells us that the right hand side of that equivalence is `id x` and the first Functor law tells us that the left hand side is `id x`.

```
f <$> x = pure f <*> x
id <$> x = pure id <*> x  -- Substitute id into the general form
id <$> x = x              -- Apply the applicative identity law
id x = x                  -- Apply the first functor law
x = x                     -- simplify id x to x
```

There we have shown that `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` obeys the first functor law by applying the applicative laws.

Comment: So, in the end, it arises from parametricity and the Identity law alone.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what this means: "that fmap f x = pure f <*> x obeys the fmap id = id law". What does it mean for an equation to mean something?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Think of it as an equality rather than equation. What it is saying is that `fmap f x` is equivalent to `pure f <*> x`. By inserting `id` as `f` on both sides of the equality we see that the equivalence is true only if `fmap id = id`

Comment: I do not see what this proof does. A correct proof must have `f <$> x = pure f <*> x` as a conclusion. However, your proof starts off with this as a premise, and derives `x = x`. Why does that imply the original statement is true?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay The style of this proof is somewhat strange; it isn't showing that `f <$> x = pure f <*> x` directly, it is just showing that `id <$> x = pure id <*> x` (the first line there is completely superfluous). Then, due to the uniqueness of `fmap`, for any function `q` satisfying `q id = id`, you also have `q = fmap` (up to extensionality of course). In this case we simply set `q = \f x -> pure f <*> x` and then the necessary condition for `q = fmap` to be true is `q id = id = \x -> pure id <*> x` (in other words, `x = pure id <*> x`). This necessary condition is what is proved

Comment: Nice answer, but please add the explanation why “it sufficies to show that `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` obeys the `fmap id = id` law” to the post itself, as it's really crucial here.